# Why pg_restore has modified a database not specified in the command?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

I did a backup with `pg_dump` of a database called **database_a** (whose PostgreSQL owner was **ubuntu**) in the server A. I called **database_a_bkp.dump** to the resultant file.

Afterwards, I went to other server B. In this server B, there was another different database also called **database_a**, whose PostgreSQL owner was **odoo**. But I created a new one named **database_b**, whose owner was **ubuntu**, to do the restoration there.

I executed the following command:

```
pg_restore --create --clean -U ubuntu -d database_b database_a_bkp.dump
```

However, unfortunately, this command altered the **database_a**, instead of restoring data in **database_b**. The **database_a** owner changed to **ubuntu**. I needed to move the owner to **odoo** again and do a REASSIGN OWNED query.

But there were more changes. For example, so far I realized that the `nextval` of the ID `pg_sequences` has changed, resulting in a lot of errors in **database_a**.

How is this possible? What was the mistake? I can fix those `nextval`, but I'm afraid of those are not the only things that the `pg_restore` has changed. Does anyone know the reason and how many things can have been altered in **database_a**?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `--create`. `pg_restore` connects to `database_b`, tries to drop `database_a` (because of `--clean`), creates it again, connects to it and restores the data.

Omit `--create` and `--clean`, and it will do what you want.

Comment: Do you mean that the *database_a* of the server B has been destroyed??? I will kill myself if so. But now, in *database_a* of server B, I can still see records which do not exist in the *database_a* of the server A. Like if there were a lot of things which `pg_restore` was not able to drop. Does this mean that it was not dropped?

Comment: I mean, why `pg_restore` with `--create` would connect to *database_b* and drop *database_a* (a database whose owner is other PostgreSQL user). Is because the content inside the *database_a_bkp.dump* file?

Comment: Why it would do that is because of --clean used with --create.  Dropping things is what --clean is for. Whether it actually destroyed the database depends on whether 'ubuntu' had permissions to do that, it might have failed.  Yes, the name of the database to operate on is stored in the -Fc dump file (but that name is only used with --create, otherwise it is present but unused.)

Comment: I have clarified my answer. I can only recommend to read the documentation before you run a command on a database with important data in it.